Install El Capitan and Big Sur on newer Mac
I have a 2019 macbook pro with Monterey installed. I am usually reluctant of switching to the newest OSX because cubase and other daw are not always compatible.
I would not think about maintaining older OS Versions if it wasn't for Cubase and some plugins, as I have older projects on older versions of cubase which are not supported on newer OS, so they "force me" to maintain older Cubase Versions and thus older OS.
I recently tried to install el Cap and High Sierra on my Mac, when I still had Big Sur installed I believe, but failed: if I remember right because of the filesystem or something like that, or even a hardware issue.
I believe I wasn't even able to install it on an empty external hard disk. may that be? Like your computer is too new to run El Cap so you can't install it with it? (I still have a 2008 macbookpro laying around, which could do so)
Can anyone help me on how to proceed properly? (I do not ask on help to create startup disk or so, I know that) I just do not understand too well intrinsics of hardware and software restrictions of apple.

MacBook Pro models from 2019 will run either Mojave 10.14 or Catalina 10.15 as their minimum version OS. There was a change in minimum version in November 2019, a new hardware release after the release of 10.15.
You don't specify which exact 2019 model yours is, but beside that, any Mac model will not officially run an OS earlier than the version originally supplied with it, hence why it won't install El Capitan or High Sierra.

Just as an edit: Both answers are right, so I had to choose. this one's more specific about OS versions.

Think of it this way: the Operating System is a set of instructions for the hardware.
El Capitan was released in 2015. The last update was 2016.
It's just not possible for a 2016 OS to know how a computer from the future works. El Capitan has a list of Macs that it knows, and your Mac is not one of them. It doesn't have the necessary drivers to make everything work.
The latest version of Cubase (13) runs on Monterey and above. Realistically, you need to update Cubase so that you can run your old projects on the new computer.

thanks... well described. The problem with cubase itself is it changes also over time, also changes available factory plugins etc. so run older cubase projects on newer cubase is usually also not possible, hence the need to be able to run older cubase versions.

@CaneloDigital For better or worse, nothing in computing stays still. It's like a garden that needs constant attention. You could either buy an old Mac  (e.g. a 2012 Mini), just for your old projects; or spend some time updating the projects in the new version of Cubase, so that you get the sound you want, even if that means using other plug-ins. (And always make sure you have final audio bounces, if nothing else works!)
